# Where can I find standard validation rules?

Tags: validation-rule, validation, data, entitlements, work-order

In a developer org, although validation rule lists are empty, checks are performed against data. E.g. trying to create an Entitlement record may lead to an error "The number of Remaining Work Orders must be less than or equal to the number of Work Orders per Entitlement" or "The end date must be equal to or later than the start date". That makes sense of course, but where can I find a list of all these data checks?

Comment: Validation can be implemented in triggers (apex code) by adding errors to records or their fields.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know where I can find default data checks like the exemplars in my question, not where I can define validation rules. Triggers seen in the front end of the Salesforce developer org are also empty like validation rules.

Comment: I was simply pointing out that not all validation is performed using validation rules. Since you are talking about standard objects, some validations are implemented within the platform. Why do you ask your question? What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Ah, understood. I want to check data records for correctness before uploading them.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a lot of standard validation that goes on. Accordingly, there's not one single page describes every possible validation. It'd be a very, very large list. Instead, there's the [Standard Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) page. Validations and special access rules are mostly listed on the relevant object. Additional places to check are the in the Help & Training for a given object. Ultimately, you'll have to do some research when you start working with a new object.